# Get a html site "input" element by python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm really stuck here.
I use Python + Selenium to automate a website form filling.
So I gave some data into the webpage, then "click" on a button, after that a new value appears in an element and I would like to get that value, but I stuck.

How should I get that value into a variable?
I tried to use find_element_by_xpath what works for "click", works for "send.keys", but to get any value from here, nothing.

Please help me!

Picture enclosed about the webpage inspection.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHgL1.png)

'''python

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://...')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[parameter- 
name="moduleId"]').send_keys('1234')
```

'''

So by that point everything is ok. I can fill the "moduleId" element with the 1234 value.

but from here I cannot read it back.
so If I try like this:

'''python

```
moduleId = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@parameter-name="moduleId"]')
```

'''

the output is nothing.

Here is the HTML part of the website what is interesting.

```
   html
   <input type="text" name="parameterValue" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="Value" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" data-bind="value:
   value, valueUpdate: 'keyup', autocomplete: { options: options, filtered: 
   true }, attr: { 'parameter-name': name, type: inputType }" parameter-name="moduleId">
```

Comment: Since you do not show any code I only have to guess that you are missing `elemenet.get_attribute("value")` (or whatever the Python equivalent is).

Comment: Please post html sample, and show what you have coded so far / what problem you're having. Stackoverflow is not for writing code for you, but for helping you with your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get the value of the input element:

```
input.get_attribute('value')
```

You could also do this all in one shot, example

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@parameter-name="moduleId"]').get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: Thank you @scilence for the help. unfortunately I have this error message:

Comment: File "C:/Users/zolag/Desktop/Legrand/scraper.py", line 38, in <module>

Comment: moduleId_value = input.get_attribute('value')

Comment: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: You would most likely want to use `moduleId_value = moduleId.get_attribute('value')`
You need to specify where to get the attribute 'value' from. 'input' is not a predefined method or variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thx4 @scilence

I made this modification:

```
moduleId = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@parameter-name="moduleId"]')
moduleId_value = moduleId.get_attribute('value')
print("data: ",moduleId_value)
```

and the output is what I need!